# Selenium using Java - Not able to Locate Webelements on Google Search Page

Tags: java, selenium

I want to search Prime Video on Google Home Page and then I want to click on News Link on Google Search Page. I have used xpath to find this Link but while executing the code, I am getting NoSuchElementException. I have used below code, Please help me to know that why below code is not working ::

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Users/gecko/geckodriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
ele.sendKeys("prime video");
ele.submit();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement news = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='hdtb-msb-vis']//div[text()='News']")));
    news.click();
    driver.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this one. I see you forgot to **Click();** as well.
Unlocate element has a several causes. One of this cause is xpath is invalid or not found on that page. One way to check is using find.element then use your xpath if it does not found it will throw an exception. Here is an example.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
/*wait page for 2 seconds -- simple way wait, but don't recommended for using real testing*/
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).Click;
driver.sendKeys("prime video");
driver.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

then try to verify if xpath is valid or invalid by using

```
try
{   
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='hdtb-msb-vis']//div[text()='News']")).Click;
}
catch(NoSuchElementException ex)
{
   System.out.println("There is no element in this page or xpath is invalid : "+ex.Message);
 }
catch(Exception ex)
{
  System.out.println("Exception : "+ex.Message);
}
```

If xpath is invalid or not found, you may try **Katalon Recorder** or **Chropath** extension for chrome to let help to find xpath.

**Katalon Record**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid

**Chropath**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with a slightly different xpath:

```
WebElement news = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"hdtb-msb-vis\"]/div[2]/a")));
```